# +1 button with custom button

Tags: opengl-es, google-plus

I've got a game running OpenGL ES, so I'm not using Android's UI components at all (except for surface view). What I would like to do is have a link to Google Plus in my game, which players could press and recommend my game to their friends in Google Plus.

I found a sample in Android Developer guides how to do this in Java. Just add a PlusOneButton and it just works. The problem is, it's really difficult to combine Android UI with my OpenGL ES based UI framework. That's why I'd like to do it myself. I already have a button which has +1 bitmap on it. The problem is that there's no apparent public method to call in PlusOneButton. I tried using following code

```
Runnable r = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        mPlusOneButton.performClick();
    }
};
m_parent.runOnUiThread(r);
```

but it doesn't seem to do anything. So simply put, how do I initiate "+1" procedure without having user actually clicking the +1 button, in other words, how do I initiate it programmatically?

Comment: I would guess that Google does their best to avoid you from achieving this goal. Otherwise any program could +1 themselves automatically. Though I would suggest you simply overlay the +1 button on top of your GLSurfaceView.

Comment: Too bad.It will look ugly and be awkward to use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Google+ API does not allow developer apps to act on a user's behalf--all activities such as +1s and Shares must be user-initiated. The intent is to prevent programmatically-created actions that could be perceived as spam, and instead to encourage meaningful sharing.